# What Magick++ equivalent code for imagemagick convert command?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Could you please help me translate below command to Magick++ equivalent code?

convert -size 720x480 -depth 16 uyvy:frame.raw frame.png

Answer (score 1):

You would need to allocated the `Magick::Image` class, set properties, and then read the image file.

```cpp
Magick::Image img;
img.size(Magick::Geometry(720, 480));
img.depth(16);
img.read("uyvy:frame.raw");
img.write("frame.png");
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.After doing the changes, frame.png file is generated but it is same as frame.raw file, only file extension is changed. When i used command line tool it generated a correct image file.

Comment: I can't offer much help as to way the UYVY is not rendering correctly. Testing the answer against files provided @ http://www.sunrayimage.com/examples.html work as expected. (note: I previously had depth set to 8, not 16 as required by your CLI command)